# Replace column name with filename

Tags: awk, sed

I have multiple text files in a directory, and am looking to change the column name based on the filename.

```
 > Text1.out - filename
 counts  -column name
 apples
 pears
 oranges
```

Required output

```
> Text1.out - filename
 Text1_counts  -column name (change column name to filename using the string before the . )
 apples
 pears
 oranges
```

I tried

```
 awk -F, 'NR==1{split(FILENAME,a,".");split($1,b,"(");$1= a[1] "_" b[1]}1' Text1.out >Text1.out.counts
```

And it worked, but when I try to do for multiple  files using awk inplace I get errors

```
awk -i inplace -F, 'NR==1{split(FILENAME,a,".");split($1,b,"(");$1= a[1] "_" b[1]}1' *.out
```

Error message or rather it points that my usage is wrong

```
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
```

Any other method to rename this would also be fine. I think my terminal does not support awk inplace replacements.

Comment: Update post with the the message I get. was not really an error message so did not include before. FNR did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps `sed` is a better alternative here

```
$ for f in file*; do sed -i '1s/.*/'"$f"'_&/' "$f"; done
```